# Kubuntu can't boot because of accidentally deleted theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm pretty new to Linux and thought no harm could be done by changing a theme. But I came to remove the active theme and now it won't boot. It only shows an on-screen keyboard and asks me to choose a different theme, but everything seems to be stuck there and I can't do anything.

Tried boot repair from a live USB drive but it ends with following:

```
(glade2script:10037): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:04:41.042: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(glade2script:10037): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:04:41.042: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:69:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(glade2script:10037): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:04:41.042: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:73:46: The style property GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(glade2script:10037): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:04:41.367: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(glade2script:10037): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:04:41.368: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(glade2script:10037): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:04:41.368: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(glade2script:10037): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:04:41.368: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(glade2script:10037): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 15:04:41.368: g_dbus_proxy_new: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
```

Is there someone who can tell me how to change a theme on the harddisk installation from a live USB pendrive? Or tell me how else to fix this - other than re-installing from scratch?
Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: Kubuntu or Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you delete the default theme or just change to another one?

Comment: I did replace it with another one, at least that was the idea. But apparently I came to delete the active one, that's the only explanation that would make sense to me, and it's Kubuntu.

Comment: I'vr reinstalled since I realised that any attempt to repair this probably would take more time than a reinstall and since it was a pretty new installation anyway it was rather painless. But still would like to know how such a thing can be fixed.